# Subtract a number from a column while maintaining the rest

Tags: awk

I am trying to substract a number (1) from a column in a file, maintaining the rest of the columns, but this is not working:

My file:

```
5    7    8    9
4    6    3    9
1    9    4    6
```

Desired output:

```
5    6    8    9
4    5    3    9
1    8    4    6
```

I was trying:

```
awk -v OFS='\t', -F='\t', '{print $1,$2-1,$3,$4}' my_file.tsv > my_out.tsv
```

But this is not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set FS and OFS to exactly a tab character (preferably in the BEGIN block), and don't bother writing all fields explicitly.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$2-=1} 1' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Issues with OP's code:

- `-v OFS='\t',` extra comma
- `-F='\t',` extra `=` and extra comma

  - or use `-v FS='\t'`